# How to dynamically skip a test in nightwatch?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have six test cases that I need to run, but only three of the test cases can be active in the test target environment at any one time.  When I run a test, I want to check if the environment is setup correctly for that particular case. If not, I want to mark the test as skipped.  How can I dynamically mark the test case as skipped in nightwatch?

Comment: sounds like you should make your tests more independent of the environment they run on.

Comment: These are for end to end test where I am not doing content seeding. I can only test what is currently configured in the environment. I am sharing this test environment with others so I cannot make it 100% deterministic.

Comment: Could all 6 tests run in the environment, the order is just important, or is it that only 3 tests total can run before you need to reset the test environment?

Answer (score 0):

From your question i can imagine that you are looking for something like this: [test tags](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#test-tags)

Comment: No, the test figures out it needs to be skipped at run time.  This would be the equivalent in the java world and testng where you throw a SkipException. This marks the test as skipped in the reporting.